# Problem Sending Server Side Messages from BlazeDS to All Browsers

Tags: java, apache-flex, coldfusion, blazeds

I've run into a bit of a wall with sending messages from BlazeDS on the server to Flex clients. I have my adapters and destinations set properly (I think) messaging-config.xml and my streaming channel setup in my services-config.xml files. The messages work beautifully in Safari (Mac and PC) but no other browsers.

relevant Bits from messaging-config.xml
Adapter:

Destination:

```
<destination id="FriendNotifierGateway">
<adapter ref="friendNotifierAdapter" />
<properties>
  <server>
    <max-cache-size>1000</max-cache-size> 
    <durable>true</durable>
    <allow-subtopics>true</allow-subtopics>
    <subtopic-separator>.</subtopic-separator>
  </server>
</properties>        
<channels>
    <channel ref="my-streaming-amf"/>
    <channel ref="cf-polling-amf"/>
</channels>
```

Relevant Bits from services-config.xml

```
<channel-definition id="my-streaming-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel">
      <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfsecure/streamingamf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.StreamingAMFEndpoint" /> 
      <properties>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes> 
        <max-streaming-clients>500</max-streaming-clients> 
        <server-to-client-heartbeat-millis>5000</server-to-client-heartbeat-millis> 
        <user-agent-settings>
          <user-agent match-on="MSIE" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="1" /> 
          <user-agent match-on="Firefox" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="4" /> 
          <user-agent match-on="Safari" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="3" />
          <user-agent match-on="Opera" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="3" />
          <user-agent match-on="Chrome" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="3" />   
        </user-agent-settings>
      </properties>
```

I feel like things are setup correctly in the channel definition but, perhaps, some of those user-agent settings are off (I have played with their settings, to no avail thus far).

Thanks, in advance, for any suggestions or insights!

Regards,
Craig

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to get to and I'm currently doing a reinstall, so I can't play, but have you seen my series of articles on BlazeDS, ColdFusion and the Flex/Ajax Bridge? http://nil.checksite.co.uk/index.cfm/BlazeDS  The config stuff might help.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I'll check it out. My goal is simply to send messages from the server to the Flex client (we're using Railo 3.2 RC2, Tomcat 7, and BlazeDS 3.x). All messaging works from the server to the client in Safari but all other browsers fail (i.e., the messages are not sent to the browser).

Comment: Do the messages just disappear into the ether, or are they generating exceptions on the client? Do you know they are actually getting sent to all the clients?

Comment: Gregor: the messages just flat-out disappear! No exceptions and I know they'

Comment: Sorry -- hit enter by mistake :) ... I know they are firing as I've debugged on the server-side. Thanks!

Comment: If you can create a test project reproducing your problem I can take a look on it

Comment: Cornel: thanks! I actually ended up killing this approach (never got it sorted) and setup ActiveMQ and hooked that into Tomcat/Railo. Ever since, the messaging has been money :)!

Answer (score 0):

I never sorted out why the server-side messages never reached the client. However, my setup was less than ideal for an active site. So, I switched to using ActiveMQ and, ever since, the messaging has been fantastic!